# setTimer() to generate WM_TIMER message only once

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using timers with resource ID added and based on WM_TIMER message. 
I would like to call a routine like `DrunkenDragon()` on `OnTimer()` but for only once after `SetTimer(id,10sec,NULL)` was called. We know that Call to `KillTimer()` inside `DrunkenDragon()` routine would fix the solution. Is it okay to go with this, or am I missing out something great with timers.

Comment: Why resource-id? You can use a counter variable to check if timer is fired first time or not.

Answer (score 1):

(Only answering this in case someone else comes across it like I did and was unsatisfied with the answers available)

So, in WindowClass.h, what you can do is an enumeration of the timer identifiers you want to use. While you certainly can use raw numeric values, using symbols is probably easier to work with in the long run.

```
class WindowClass : CWnd
{
    // other parts of the interface...

protected:

    enum
    {
        TIMER_MAIN_UPDATE = 1,
        TIMER_PLASTERED_DRAGON
    };
};
```

Meanwhile, back at in WindowClass.cpp,

```
int WindowClass::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    // { ... other initialization code }

    // In case you want to do other types of updates at regular intervals.
    SetTimer(TIMER_MAIN_UPDATE, 1000, NULL);

    // Note the symbolic identifiers.
    SetTimer(TIMER_PLASTERED_DRAGON, 10000, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

That's only any good if you want to do it 10 seconds after the window's been created, though. You can also just call SetTimer() in some other event handler whenever you'd like:

```
void WindowClass::OnJustGotPaid()
{
    // { ... other handling }

    // Since our dragon is a real lightweight, it apparently only takes
    // 10 seconds to get him puking up flaming vomit.
    SetTimer(TIMER_PLASTERED_DRAGON, 10000, NULL);
}
```

When it comes time for the actual event to be handled, it is typically handled in the Windows OnTimer() callback. A timer event can be directed to a different (custom) callback, if desired, by specifying a valid function pointer in SetTimer()'s third parameter instead of NULL.

```
void WindowClass::OnTimer(UINT_PTR p_timer_id)
{
    switch(p_timer_id)
    {

    default:
        break;

    case TIMER_MAIN_UPDATE:

        // { ... main update code }
        break;

    case TIMER_PLASTERED_DRAGON:

        // Killing the timer first in case DrunkenDragon() takes a good
        // long while for whatever reason.
        KillTimer(TIMER_PLASTERED_DRAGON);

        DrunkenDragon();

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int CYourDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
   __super::OnInitDialog();

   SetTimer(0x10, 10000, NULL);

   return true;
}

void CYourDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR ignore)
{
   DrunkenDragon();
}
```

And ensure you have `ON_WM_TIMER` in message-map.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything and you would have to use KillTimer for system to stop generating WM_TIMER messages.

You can also use CreateTimerQueueTimer and set parameters the way a callback is called only once.

[See this for more details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)